# Indoor Atlas: iOS SDK doesn't give accurate position when device stops moving

Tags: ios, iphone, indoor-positioning-system

I downloaded the Indoor Atlas iPhone SDK and also generated path maps and test paths for my venue. SDK navigates me perfectly when I am moving from one place to another but when I stop moving it generates scattered output with the position radius from 10 to 25. I am expecting precise co-ordinates in both the above cases in my project.

Is there any way to get more precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IndoorAtlas technology is using the history of magnetic field observations for computing the precise location. This means that the device needs to move some distance in order to collect enough data to converge to a correct location estimate, i.e., to have a location fix. We are constantly improving our service to decrease the time needed for the first location fix.

If you experience your position moving after you've already stopped walking yourself, please contact support@indooratlas.com with details of your application and venue where this is experienced and we'll look into it. Thanks!